# overriding asp.net mvc 5 body margins

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

This may be a very simple HTML/CSS issue, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have made an ASP.NET MVC 5 program, and I am trying to make a visual display type screen, and I have placed a raphael image into a table with three scrolling lists but I cannot seem to get the table to run over the margins on the right side of the screen. I am guessing this has something to do with the boostrap css but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I have tried altering the container padding and margins, and the table width, but I cannot seem to get the right three columns to extend far enough that the text in the list isn't forced to wrap. I am able to alter the left-margin and move everything over to the left, but I cannot get the table to extend any further to the right.

I am not super experienced with HTML or CSS so any input is truly appreciated! Hopefully its something

Table Code:

```
    <table style="width: 100%" align="Left" border="1">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3"><div id="canvas_container"></div></td>
    <td>
        <header>List 1</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <header>List 2</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>item 15</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <header>List 3</header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>item 21</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the canvas_container div tag is my raphael object.

I have also tried changing the .body-content padding and margins and I cannot figure out what I need to do.

I do not have enough reputation points to post a picture, I apologize that I cant show exactly what I am talking about

Comment: It is difficult for us to diagnose without seeing the rest of the code/css, but have you tried setting the width of <td> directly and see if that has the wanted effect?

Comment: What is surrounding the table? Any DIVs or other tags?

Comment: I tried updating the DIV width but it didnt make any change.

Comment: And the table is is inside a partial view one a page that uses a layout page. it renders the body inside the   <div class="container body-content"> tag. I have tried manipulating the margins and padding for that tag but it does not seem to allow the table to span to the right anymore

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing the surrounding `<div class="container body-content">` tag to `<div class="container-fluid body-content">`

Comment: I found "container body-content" in the Layout.cshtml.  Then I created a new Layout2.cshtml file and set my page to that layout.